# Изменить атрибуты у всех файлов в каталоге

Tags: c++

Функция

```
fs::remove_all("d:/temp/1");
```

удаляет каталог, если в нем нет файлов с атрибутами, например только для чтения.
Если есть атрибуты, то удаление не произойдет.
Для файла можно изменить атрибуты

```
fs::permissions("d:/temp/1/1.txt", fs::perms::all);
```

Какие есть варианты изменить атрибуты для всех файлов в каталоге?

Comment: Перебрать все файлы в цикле, не?
for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator("d:/temp/1")) {...}

Comment: видимо так и надо. удобные функции с++17 в данном случае бесполезны. еще попробовать вызвать rd /s /q d:\temp\1